# Database replication SQL Server 2012 to Bigrock server and Windows Server on AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, sql-server-2012, web-hosting, transactional-replication

I am developing windows application where I am trying to create `SQL Server 2012` database replication to [`Bigrock server`](http://www.bigrock.in/) and [Windows Server on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/windows/)
but failed to perform database replication.

I publish database on `SQL Server 2012` and trying to add subscription of `Bigrock server` and `Windows Server on AWS` server database but it gives me following error :

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a
>   connection to the server. Specify the actual server name

I also refer [Transactional Replication in SQL Server](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/transactional-replication-2008-r2/) link

can anyone tell me it is possible ?  if yes then how ?

Comment: You may be better off asking here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/.  I don't know enough about AWS to answer, but I suspect if you have VPN available and appropriate whitelists to allow the servers to see one another it should be possible.